# CURL7.76.0 curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'errormsg'

Tags: curl

CURL version: **7.76.0**.
OS: **MacOS**

The [documentaition](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) says:

> ```
> -w, --write-out <format>
> ```
>
> **errormsg** The error message. (Added in 7.75.0)
> **exitcode** The numerical exitcode of the transfer. (Added in 7.75.0)
> **onerror** The rest of the output is only shown if the transfer returned a non-zero error (Added in 7.75.0)

But using them inside Terminal:

```
curl -s -w "%{errormsg}\n%{exitcode}\n%{onerror}\n" "https://api.github.com/users/lambda" >> log.txt
```

I am getting:

> curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'errormsg'
> curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'exitcode'
> curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'onerror'

Could somebody please shed some light?

Comment: @DanielStenberg default-installed curl? Do we have to manually remove the default-installed curl and reinstall a newer version?